# Transferring Attributes in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, data-transfer

Is there a way to reload a previous transfer attribute definition that I made?

In case my source and target schemes are the same.

Here's an example:

I've already defined field mapping between Makleb 4601 to water line, and now I want to do the same field mapping to Makleb 4603 and water Line

Is there a way to save the field mapping and reload it?

[image]